# jQuery width returns 0 for even when window is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, width

I am having an issue with a jQuery css('width') value inside a $(window).load function in Chrome and Safari.

*Normal behaviour:*

The page loads, visitor hovers an element of the menu, the sub menu appears with correct column widths.

*Actual bug occurs when:*

The user accesses the website, doesn't wait until the page is fully loaded to hover a menu item... after a few seconds the sub menu's columns collapse.

You can see it live on http://www.pharmagooddeal.fr/beta678/ (use Chrome or Safari). Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the collapsed columns]

Basically what happens is a JS file kicks in to resize different menu elements on window load.

Here is the script's content (I didn't code it myself) :

```
$(window).load(function(){
    resizeWidth();

(function($,sr){
  // debouncing function from John Hann
  // http://unscriptable.com/index.php/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/
  var debounce = function (func, threshold, execAsap) {
      var timeout;

      return function debounced () {
          var obj = this, args = arguments;
          function delayed () {
              if (!execAsap)
                  func.apply(obj, args);
              timeout = null; 
          };

          if (timeout)
              clearTimeout(timeout);
          else if (execAsap)
              func.apply(obj, args);

          timeout = setTimeout(delayed, threshold || 100); 
      };
  }
// smartresize 
 jQuery.fn[sr] = function(fn){  return fn ? this.bind('resize', debounce(fn)) : this.trigger(sr); };

})(jQuery,'smartresize');


var TO = false;
$(window).resize(function(){
 if(TO !== false)
    clearTimeout(TO);
 TO = setTimeout(resizeWidth, 400); //400 is time in miliseconds
});

function resizeWidth()
{   var number1=123.15;
    var number=Math.round(number1).toFixed(2);

    var menuWidth = 1180;
    var numColumn = 5;
    var currentWidth = $("#menu").width()-2;
    if (currentWidth < menuWidth) {

        new_width_column = currentWidth / numColumn;
        $('#menu div.options_list').each(function(index, element) { 
            var options_list = $(this).next();
            var span_options_list = options_list.attr('styleWidth');
            console.log('Span options list: ' + span_options_list);
            $(this).width(parseFloat(span_options_list)/menuWidth*numColumn * new_width_column);        
        });
        $('#menu div.option').each(function(index, element) {
            var option = $(this).next();
            var woption=parseFloat(option.css("width"))/menuWidth*numColumn * new_width_column-0.5; 
            console.log('Option CSS Width: ' + option.css("width"));
            console.log('Option Width: ' + option.width());
            console.log('Option Inner Width: ' + option.innerWidth());
            console.log('Option Outer Width: ' + option.outerWidth());
            console.log('Menu Width: ' + menuWidth);
            console.log('Num column: ' + numColumn);
            console.log('New width column: ' + new_width_column);
            console.log('Woption: ' + woption);
            var woption1=Math.round(woption).toFixed(2);
            $(this).width(woption1);
            console.log('Woption1: '+woption1);
            console.log('-----------------');

            var wul= parseFloat(option.css("width"))/menuWidth*numColumn * new_width_column-0.5;
            var wul1=Math.round(wul).toFixed(2);
            $("ul", this).width(parseFloat(option.css("width"))/menuWidth*numColumn * new_width_column);

        });
        $('#menu ul.column').each(function(index, element) {
            var column = $(this).next();
            var wul=parseFloat(column.css("width"))/menuWidth*numColumn * new_width_column-0.5;
            var wul1=Math.round(wul).toFixed(2);
            $(this).width(wul1);
        });
    }

    $('#menu ul > li > a + div').each(function(index, element) {
        var menu = $('#menu').offset();
        var dropdown = $(this).parent().offset();
        i = (dropdown.left + $(this).width()) - (menu.left + $('#menu').width());
        if (i > 0) {
            $(this).css('margin-left', '-' + i + 'px');
        }
        else
            $(this).css('margin-left', '0px');
    });
}


});
```

If you scroll down to "function resizeWidth()", you can see a bunch of console.log below, I figured out where it goes wrong:

```
console.log('Option CSS Width: ' + option.css("width"));
```

This one returns a normal value if I wait until the page is loaded before I hover a menu element, or 0 if I hover before the page has finished loaded.

I have tried different things but I can't figure out what the problem is. Here is what the other console logs return:

```
Option CSS Width: 0px
csmegamenu_front.js:59 Option Width: 0
csmegamenu_front.js:60 Option Inner Width: 0
csmegamenu_front.js:61 Option Outer Width: 0
csmegamenu_front.js:62 Menu Width: 1180
csmegamenu_front.js:63 Num column: 5
csmegamenu_front.js:64 New width column: 235.6
csmegamenu_front.js:65 Woption: -0.5
csmegamenu_front.js:68 Woption1: 0.00
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: try this: option.css("width") ---> option.width()

Comment: It still returns 0.

I updated the question to show what the other console.logs return. I tried different ways to get the width's value via jQuery.